# c# - Add checked listbox checked items to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms

Well, I have a checked listbox here and I want to add the checked items to my List and then serialize them with JSON.
Example:

```
public class Customer
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Products { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(boxName.Text.Length != 0 && productsList.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = boxName.Text;
        //This is what I tried
        foreach(var item in productsList.CheckedItems)
        {
            customer.Products = item.ToString();
        }
        Customers.Add(customer);
        customersList.Items.Add(customer.Name);
    }
}

//In one event I have this to save to the JSON file
File.WriteAllText(file, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Customers));
```

But my output in JSON file and also in the Customers List is only the name of one selected product. How to get all and do something like this:

```
[{"Name":"Mathew", "Products":"car", "boat", "bike"}] //These products will be inserted according to the checked products in the checked listbox
```

How to add these values for the Products? I'm also trying to put price like this:

```
"Products": "car": "Price":"20000", "boat": "Price":"30000", "bike":"Price":"2000"
```

Someone can give me a hand? I would be very grateful if I learn this! Thanks all in advance!

Comment: You are overriding the product in the foreach loop, concatinate the string like customer.Products += item.ToString(); to prevent overriding.

Comment: @Xela this worked, but how to get comma separated products? And how I will proceed if I have to put price? Like "Products": "car": "Price":"20000", "boat": "Price":"30000", "bike":"Price":"2000"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get Json like that, as it doesn't appear to be formatted correctly. Have a look at http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/examples/

To get something like what you are after you will need to do something similar to the following

```
public class ProductDetails
{
     public string ProdName { get; set; }
     public string Price { get; set; }
}    

public class Customer
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<ProductDetails> Products { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(boxName.Text.Length != 0 && productsList.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = boxName.Text;
        customer.Products = new List<ProductDetails>();

        //This is what I tried

        foreach(var item in productsList.CheckedItems)
        {
            ProductDetails details = new ProductDetails()
            details.ProdName = item,ToString();
            details.Price=  5;

            customer.Products.Add(details);
        }
        Customers.Add(customer);
        customersList.Items.Add(customer.Name);
    }
}
```

This should give you an output like the following

```
[{"Name":"Mathew", "Products": [{ "ProdName" : "car", "Price": "1000"}, {"ProdName":"boat", "Price": "10"}, {"ProdName": "bike", "Price" : "5"}]}]
```

*Note i just typed this off the top of my head, there could be a few errors, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.